# Highcharts Graphic Objects Alignment

Tags: highcharts

```
                $(function () {
                    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
                        chart: {
                            renderTo: 'container',
                            backgroundColor: 'white',
                            events: {
                                load: function () {

                                    // Draw the flow chart
                                    var ren = this.renderer,
                                        colors = Highcharts.getOptions().colors,
                                        rightArrow = ['M', 0, 0, 'L', 100, 0, 'L', 95, 5, 'M', 100, 0, 'L', 95, -5],
                                        leftArrow = ['M', 100, 0, 'L', 0, 0, 'L', 5, 5, 'M', 0, 0, 'L', 5, -5];               
                                    ren.label('Relatively aligned Text', 210, 200)
                                        .attr({
                                            r: 5,
                                            width: 100,
                                            fill: colors[1]
                                        })
                                        .css({
                                            color: 'white',
                                            fontWeight: 'bold'
                                        })
                                        .add();                   
                                }
                            }
                        }        
                    });
                });
```

By using the following code I have managed to render a label , but If if I change browser size its position wont be changing , how to give the position to render chart responsive to browser resolution size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to catch $(window).resize() or redraw() events in the chart and destroy/create new one or correct position.